# Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve: com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.1.0

Tags: android

My Android project was working well before two days with `material dialog library 0.7.6.0`, but from last two days `gradle` sync fail with

```
Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve: com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.6.0
```

So as per solutions on stack overflow I followed new library, but still Gradle can't build successfully.Here is my Gradle dependencies:

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
   }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.1.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0 or latter version

```
  dependencies { 
       implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    }

     buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }

     allprojects {

        repositories {
/* removed maven repo from here */
               google()
            jcenter()
        }

    }
```

My Reference Link here [[Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+ (Dependency Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164768/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v727-dependency-error][1])

Answer (score 0):

Modify dependency

```
compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.2@aar')
```

Comment: new one released is 0.8.5.2

Comment: changed but throwing same error, is it depends on target SDK Version?

Answer (score 0):

I unable to build gradle with 0.8.5.2 version.

I use Custom classes from material-dialogs-0.6.1.3, its working fine in my application.