# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+ (Dependency Error)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am having this issue in Android studio.

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure 
dialog</a>
```

My Android Studio is full of error android studio cannot identify libraries. The whole screen looks like this.

[image]

This is my `Gradle` code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hp.temp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried installing repostiory and syncing project?

Comment: If you are living in some countries like iran, unfortunately google do not support your gradle, so you must use a vpn to get gradle dependencies.

Comment: Actually this answer should not be marked as duplicate as the technical requirements to the solution differ from source answer.

Comment: Add 
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    after jcenter() in project build.gradle

Answer (score 120):

Find root `build.gradle` file and add google maven repo inside `allprojects` tag

```
repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {                                  // <-- Add this
            url 'https://maven.google.com/' 
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
```

It's better to use specific version instead of variable version

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
```

---

**If you're using Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or latter version**

```
repositories {
      mavenLocal()
      mavenCentral()
      google()        //---> Add this
}
```

and inject dependency in this way :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
```

Comment: `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'` How do I decide what version to specify? Still gives dex error. `v7:27.0.1` or `v7:27.0.2`

Comment: I always prefer to use latest version, current latest is `27.0.2`, enable multidex if you're getting dex error.

Comment: `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex`

Continuously getting this error. I have done many fixes, but nothing helps. Also, When I set `CompileSdkVersion 26`, it compiles but app crashes in the phone.
 I have also enabled the multidex support, still the same issue.

Comment: @RahulParashar ask a new question with complete `build.gradle` file of android module, without knowing all your injected library I can't help you.

Comment: @Aryan  I found that also including "google()" in the "allprojects" of your project gradle will complete the build, in addition to the answer above

Comment: @giulio repo link can only be added in `repositories` tag which is part of `allprojects` or `buildscript` tag in root `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Adding repositories does not solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 57):

If you are using **Android Studio 3.0 or above** make sure your project **build.gradle** should have content similar to-

```
buildscript {                 
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {            
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Note-** position really matters add **google()** before **jcenter()**

And for **below Android Studio 3.0** and starting from **support libraries 26.+** your project **build.gradle** must look like this-

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

check these links below for more details-

**1-** [Building Android Apps](https://guides.gradle.org/building-android-apps/)

**2-** [Add Build Dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html)

**3-** [Configure Your Build](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html)

Comment: Google must be set before jcenter, as you did, or the error will continue to appear

Comment: correct @Ben-J position really matters :)

Comment: Putting google before jcenter solves the problem for me!