# Fixing gradle error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I create a new Project in Android Studio I get this problems , I don't Know how to resolve them , I'm using Android Studio Version 3.0.1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJlDo.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jknNv.jpg)

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.

and about the code there are No Problem in the code , I don't Know ?

Comment: Show some code in an [edit].

Comment: I added two pictures you can see them after the description : " 


When I create a new Project in Android Studio I get this problems , I don't Know how to resolve them , I'm using Android Studio Version 3.0.1 


enter image description here


enter image description here  "

Comment: I don't Know They don't show me a problem in the code but They give me this errors , sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: Add code as text, please, not as image. Reasons: [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1288408)

Comment: I wrote the errors !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103230/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportcardview-v726-0-0-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+ (Dependency Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164768/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v727-dependency-error)

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle (Project level) just replace `jcenter()` for `maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}` in both `repositories` and `allprojects` scopes

That will fix it.

Explanation:

By default, `jcenter` points to a https url, and by some reason, the SSL certificate is not working.
If I helped you, please score this answer.
Greetings from Brazil!