# Error in android studio project and in IDE as well

Tags: android

I am facing completely unaware about this error, means why this is being thrown?

```
Error:Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.
Required by:
    accounts-android:app:unspecified
    accounts-android:app:unspecified > com.android.support:design:25.3.1

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
```

but this is not about to [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+ (Dependency Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164768/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v727-dependency-error) .

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried installing the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+ (Dependency Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164768/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v727-dependency-error)

Comment: Yes sir but i have done after seeing another error.

Comment: No  Amit Vaghela Sir this is not about Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+ (Dependency Error)

Comment: Who has marked as duplicate?

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.2.0' 
try this

Comment: Sir i am not using ' com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+' library.   v7:25 is being used

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1' is being used in my project.

Comment: @ShadabAazam show us your gradle dependencies here

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${RETROFIT_VERSION}"
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'

Comment: compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${RETROFIT_VERSION}"
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.kyanogen.signatureview:signature-view:1.1@aar'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'

Comment: @Waleem Asim Sir this is complete dependencies of gradle

Answer (score 3):

I solve the problem by replacing compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)' by 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'