# AdMob Notification About Google Mobile Ads SDK Version. Need Explanation

Tags: android-studio, admob

As you already know that

> "Beginning Jan 23, 2018, Google Mobile Ads SDK versions older than
>   7.0.0 for Android and 7.0.0 for iOS will no longer be supported".

Above statement mean this ? ===>

```
"compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'"
```

I am confuse that I am using correct Google Mobile Ads SDK Version or not? OR I need to check something else?

Comment: I am using the same version in my app
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
Now should i do some thing else or my project will be ok and it will show ads after jan 23? please help i am very confuse

Answer (score 2):

No need to do anything, you already using **10.0.1** version which is greater then **7.0.0**, however you can update to current latest version which is **11.8.0**.

---

[Google Mobile Ads SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/sdk) offered for Android through [Google Play services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) which is available from the Google maven repository.

> ```
> Google Mobile Ads          com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0
> ```

Google Mobile Ads API dependency injection

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aryan. Just changing 10.0.1 into 11.8.0 will upgrade my Google Mobile Ads SDK version???? or I need to do something else?

Comment: updating version and gradle sync is enough but may be you can face some issue at the time of syncing because from version 11.2.0, you've to use the google maven repo so follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47165271/3445320)

Comment: @awais I am using the same version in my app
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
Now should i do some thing else or my project will be ok and it will show ads after jan 23? please help i am very confuse

Comment: @PirFahimShah Don't be confused, You're using version `10.0.1`, which is greater then `7.0.0` so don't worry. Form ads version context no problem for your app after 23 jan.

Comment: @Aryan but i am not using these 2 lines of code in my app, should i put that code now
1:
maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
2:  MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-5900269475646349~3669xxxx");

is that line necessary for the app to load add or my old app is ok

Comment: It is only required if you update version to latest version. From version `11.2.0`, we need to add google maven repo link so that gradle fetch artifacts from repository.

Comment: Google recommend to use  `MobileAds.initialize(XXXXX)` but it is not necessary. The Mobile Ads SDK take a few milliseconds to initialize itself so Ad SDK have provided initialize(..) method to call it way before you even call your first ad. Once that is done, there would not be any added load time for your first request. If you do not call this, then your very first AdRequest would take a few milliseconds more as it first needs to initialize itself.

Comment: @Aryan Thanks brother, so i should not change my source code and my ap will serve ads right? Only i need to migrate my Eclipse project to android studio? right please also elaborate me about eclipse project, should i change them to android studio?,  Please help me i have these question and i will much appreciate it brother.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162956/discussion-between-pir-fahim-shah-and-aryan).

Comment: For `23 Jan` issue no need to do anything. I always prefer to use latest version of any stable artifact so its good to update your artifact version to `11.8.0` and use `MobileAds.initialize(XXXXX)` as it is google recommendation. Android Studio is far good for Android development so It's good to migrate on Android Studio.