# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0

Tags: android, api, gradle, android-appcompat

So, I built an app using targetSdkVersion 25, but then I realized that it's necessary to be higher than 26. I tried to upgrade it to API 27 and I am getting this error:

> Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0

Under this message there are three options:

- Install Repository and sync project
- Show in File Show in Project
- Structure dialog

My build.gradle(Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.simon.onequoteaday"
        minSdkVersion 14 //9
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

I've also installed all API 27 SDK.
Any possible solutions? Thank you

Edit:
I've already used the solution provided by other threads but they don't solve my problem. I think my problem is different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164768/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v727-dependency-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+ (Dependency Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164768/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v727-dependency-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the newest Android Studio version solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    buildtoolsversion '27.0.0'
```

and dependencies as:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
```

and stay connected to internet and download whatever repository it asks.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I get the same error...
And also nothing happens when I click Install Repository and sync project

Answer (score 0):

replace `maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}` with `google()`; the location has changed.

Comment: My gradle version is 2.14.1 so thats not the case. If I use google() i get an error that says that the method google() could not be found. That's for later versions