# Failed to resolve: support-media-compat Open File

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading the code, I am getting an error "Failed to resolve: support-media-compat Open File". The supportlib_version is 27.1.1

[image]

Comment: it is due to your different versions of libraries in gradle file. All android supp libraries should have the same api version. please check those versions

Comment: I think I have given 27.1.1 for all support libraries.

Comment: can you post your complete .gradle file ?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue after adding implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1' and solved it by making google() before jcenter() as mentioned here [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+ (Dependency Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164768/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v727-dependency-error/47165445#47165445)

Comment: i change google() before jcenter() in **allprojects**  work for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem for different implementation

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}
    }
}
```

After adding this code in project level gradle, it worked