# I'm having these error's in my Android Studio, I'm unable to even start the project

Tags: android, android-studio

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+. Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+. Show Details Affected Modules:
>   app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+. Show Details Affected Modules:
>   app

Comment: does this solves your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47165445/10554417

Comment: I tried it but it gave a new error... ERROR: Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.2

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.example"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

}
```